# Are HTTP 304 results also counted as Operations in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Are 304 NOT MODIFIED results also counted as Operations in Google Cloud Storage and therefore billed or are they just counted if a 2xx code is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around a bit and found out that GET requests that result in a 304 response *do not count* towards the quota.

I used the quota API that is called from the Google Cloud Dashboard and compared the results after doing calls with and without force refresh.

Answer (score 2):

The [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class) says the following:

> Generally, you are not charged for operations that return 307, 4xx, or 5xx responses. The exception is 404 responses returned by buckets with Website Configuration enabled and the NotFoundPage property set to a public object in that bucket.

I assume it would count, though I'm not 100% certain.